# checking version in perl

Tags: regex, perl, version

I am writing sub routine for checking version but some how I am not getting correct output
    if version 1 < version 2 then -1
    if version 1 =  version 2 then 0
    if version1 > version 2 then 1
   Not sure Why I am not getting correct result

```
sub checkVersion
    {
        my $var1 = shift;
        my $var2 = shift;
        my @var1_seg = split (/./, $var1);
        my @var2_seg = split (/./, $var2);
        for( my $i = 0; $i < @var1_seg; $i++ ) 
        {
            if( $var1_seg[$i] < $var2_seg[$i] ) 
            {
                 return -1;
            }
            elsif( $var1_seg[$i] > $var2_seg[$i] )
            {
                 return 1;
            }
         }

      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

On one note, you need to escape the dot `.` using split as it is considered a special character in regular expression. 
Instead, use the [`version`](http://search.cpan.org/~jpeacock/version-0.97/lib/version.pod) module which makes it very easy to compare version numbers:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use version;
use feature 'say';

say checkVersion('5.10.0', '5.14.0'); # Returns -1
say checkVersion('5.10.0', '5.10.0'); # Returns  0
say checkVersion('5.14.0', '5.10.0'); # Returns  1

sub checkVersion {
   my $var1 = shift;
   my $var2 = shift;
   return version->parse($var1) <=> version->parse($var2);
}
```

Comment: Is there any logical error ? I feel something is not write on logic

Comment: Input is 4.0 and 3.0.2
I believe I have not checked if primary version are same and secondary versions are less than or more

Comment: Or just `return version->parse($var1) <=> version->parse($var2);`

Answer (score 1):

Use [version](https://metacpan.org/pod/version) Instead. This module is immensely helpful when you are dealing with versions.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this:

```
my @var1_seg = split (/./, $v1);
my @var2_seg = split (/./, $v2);
```

be this:

```
my @var1_seg = split (/./, $var1);
my @var2_seg = split (/./, $var2);
```

As a general comment, always 'use strict;' at the top of your programs to avoid problems like this.

Comment: Those are var1 and var2 only, that is typo in question not in actual script